# how can we change the date format of SQL Server(2008) Database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

For data saved via win form, the input date format is(dd/mm/yyyy). The database showsin (yyyy-mm-dd) format. How can I change date format?

```
private void btnAllocate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=HP-HP; database=Restaurent; user id=sa; password=sql2008");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WtrTblAllot (WtrNm,Type,No,currDate) values (@WtrNm,@Type,@No,@currDate)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WtrNm", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currDate", dtTmPkr.Value);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd = null;
              }
        MessageBox.Show("Added successfully!");
}
```

date time piker (dtTmPkr)  format (dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: (yyyy-mm-dd)  is the native data format of SQL server. you can change to any specific format using this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

So really, it's not about changing the date format in SQL Server - it's about **how to format** and display a `Datetime` that you retrieve from SQL Server. Use the appropriate T-SQL `CONVERT` parameters, or format the `DateTime` in your C# front-end code

**Update:** if you're inserting the value from the `DateTimePicker` into SQL Server using your query shown in the question, you should be just fine - it's inserting a `DateTime` parameter so you won't have any issues with string formatting of your dates.

When you need to convert a `DATETIME` in SQL Server to a specific format - use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), YourDateColumn, 103)
```

and this will give you a date in `dd/mm/yyyy` (British/French) format. If you need a different format - use a different style (some other number than 103). Those styles [are **very well documented** here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

If you read back the `DateTime` column into C# and you need to format it, then use

```
string formatted = YourDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

to get the values you need. Watch out: to format the **month**, use `MM` (capitalized!) because the `mm` would format the **minutes** of your `DateTime` instead.

Comment: +1 a note to the last Code block of the answer: you need to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to force / as date separator, otherwise it will be replaced with the actual date separator of your current culture (if its different).

Answer (score 0):

try to parse the Date to datetime object in c# prior to adding in Parameter.

```
DateTime Dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dtTmPkr.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currDate", Dt);
```

Comment: You are facing probelm in saving data or retriving data ?

Comment: try my above answer for saving, and for retriving try the following link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score -1):

Use this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WtrTblAllot (WtrNm,Type,No,currDate) values (@WtrNm,@Type,@No,CONVERT(CHAR(10), @currDate, 103))", con);
```

Comment: it change (yyyy/mm/dd to yyyy/dd/mm) not working... i want (dd/mm/yyyy)@Bibhu

Comment: same error (yyyy/dd/mm) and ur coding is missing the close bracket ) after 103 plz correct.@Bibhu..

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar Ashu - Check out this MSDN page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx, 103 is the code for dd/mm/yyyy.